How come nearly all of Absolver's attacks have frame advantage?
I'm new to Absolver, but I have played a few 3D fighting games before so I'm ok at understanding frame data. What I'm not quite getting about Absolver is how almost all attacks in the game are positive on block and on hit? In other 3D fighting games I've played most attacks are quite the opposite in that they are usually negative on block and mostly on hit as well, except during stuns or juggles etc.
It would be great if someone more familiar with this game could explain how this works differently in Absolver compared to other fighting games. For example, does almost always being positive on frames during attack mean you should adopt a more offense focused game style over defense? Or is there more to it than that?

By "positive," I'm assuming you mean that those attacks hit?

Positive on block/hit means that when an attack is blocked/hits it gives the attacking player a certain number of frames advantage. For example +5 on block would mean if the attacking player's attack is blocked they can launch their next attack 5 frames sooner than the defending player, which is a 5 frame advantage. The opposite (negative frames) would be a disadvantage.

That's mostly just because Absolver is just dramatically different than normal fighting games. If I hit the opponent with a hook, that's +2oB and +6oH. Those plus frames aren't being used to hit my opponent with a strike/throw mix or to go into another hook, they're to lead into heavier attacks with less risk of punishment. Absolver is more about pressuring the opponent with strings of attacks and gaining stamina advantage/guard breaks while avoiding getting mashed out of or punished by a style ability (like Forsaken's Parry) than slipping past your opponent's guard with mixups.

Welcome to Arqade! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your posts if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Could you expand on this a bit please, I'd like to understand the difference more. What I'm not clear on is in your example, after the hook, why would an Absolver player choose a heavier attack over just another hook or another fast/light attack? Since isn't a faster attack less likely to get interrupted, especially since +2 or even +6 isn't that much if the heavy attack is quite a bit slower. Secondly, does being mostly positive on block encourage more offensive play, or are there enough defensive tools to easily turn the tide and allow the other player to start attacking?
